# Getting a "Request Rejected" response when trying to access some admin pages

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have logged into my Drupal 7 site as an admin and I was trying to put the site into maintenance mode but I get this response when ever I try:

**"The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator. Your support ID is: 1272530.."**

I have checked the permissions and it seems like my admin accounts has all the permissions granted. What could be the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this method. Hope you will get result or at least you get some idea.

Option 1: Clear your cache and browser then try to hit the url.
Option 2: Try from different network.
Option 3: Try cloning your site locally and check whether it's working in local system. I think firewall may be the issue in your web site server.